# Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show only prints 2 pages at a time

Tags: excel, vba, printing

So, i've written this form overlay for an excel sheet. Long story short, all the values ends up in cells (surprise!). I have then preset a printout area a print button that calls

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
```

But every time, no matter what amount of pages to print is input, i prints out 2 copies.. What?!
I know you can use:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show arg4:=4
```

But that is just a preset so you dont have to put in 4 your self.

Do anyone have an idea of why excel is behaving like a printer prune?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason (at least in my case). A pop-up was hidden behind my form as i pressed print, that got closed down with excel, so i never saw it. For some reason (Not excel or the code) the printer or network triggered a "Data size overload" on my printing job. Explaining how printing out 100's of pages at a time could see the printer run into memory trouble. For some reason my 8 page printout triggered that.. But like all other magic, it solved it self at some point.